# How do you automatically add a '0' in front of any number 1-9 in PHP?

Tags: php

I need a way to be able to automatically add a '0' in front of any number if the number a user enters is a number between 1-9 in PHP. I need this because I am trying to make a 10 character date so that I can search for exercises added to my website between the dates.

The easiest way to do this I thought was to start with a year, then the month, then the day so I get something like this: 2001/04/15. I can just have the user manually add a '0', but I was hoping there was a way to do that automatically.

So far, I have this, but it doesn't work quite right. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

```
//Checks to see if start day is a number 1-9
//If so, adds a '0' at the beginning of the start day variable

    if($_POST['eday'] == 1 || $_POST['eday'] == 2 || $_POST['eday'] == 3 || $_POST['eday'] == 4 ||
    $_POST['eday'] == 5 || $_POST['eday'] == 6 || $_POST['eday'] == 7 || $_POST['eday'] == 8 || 
    $_POST['eday'] == 9) {
    $_POST['eday'] = 0 . $_POST['eday'];

    echo $_POST['eday'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Instead of all those different comparisons, did you consider `$_POST['eday'] < 10`?

Comment: `if($_POST['eday'] >= 1 && $_POST['eday'] <= 9) {echo "0".$_POST['eday'];}` something like that?

Comment: Also, if you're formatting dates and times, you should use the `date()` function.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks guys! Sorry, I am new to PHP so I didn't think about that

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` formatting:

```
printf("%02d<br>", $_POST['eday']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating yourself for nothing dude, you could do it like that :

```
if($_POST['eday'] < 10) $number = '0'.$_POST['eday'];
else $number = $_POST['eday'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thing: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp

```
pad_str($str,20,".");
```

will pad out to 20 characters of "."

There is and optional 4th parameter.

**STR_PAD_BOTH**

**STR_PAD_RIGHT**    *(Default if not supplied)*

**STR_PAD_LEFT**

so for you:

```
$str = $_POST['eday'];
pad_str($str,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Now `$str` is set and you can use it where ever you need.